# Flink: How to convert the deprecated fold to aggregrate?

Tags: scala, aggregate, apache-flink, fold, flink-streaming

I am following the quick start example of Flink: [Monitoring the Wikipedia Edit Stream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html).

The example is in Java, and I am implementing it in Scala, as following:

```
/**
 * Wikipedia Edit Monitoring
 */
object WikipediaEditMonitoring {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val edits: DataStream[WikipediaEditEvent] = env.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource)

    val result = edits.keyBy( _.getUser )
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .fold(("", 0L)) {
        (acc: (String, Long), event: WikipediaEditEvent) => {
          (event.getUser, acc._2 + event.getByteDiff)
        }
      }

    result.print

    // execute program
    env.execute("Wikipedia Edit Monitoring")
  }
}
```

However, the `fold` function in Flink is already **deprecated**, and the `aggregate` function is recommended.

[image]

But I did not find the example or tutorial about how to convert the deprecated `fold` to `aggregrate`.

Any idea how to do this?  Probably not only by applying `aggregrate`.

**UPDATE**

I have another implementation as following:

```
/**
 * Wikipedia Edit Monitoring
 */
object WikipediaEditMonitoring {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val edits: DataStream[WikipediaEditEvent] = env.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource)

    val result = edits
      .map( e => UserWithEdits(e.getUser, e.getByteDiff) )
      .keyBy( "user" )
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .sum("edits")

    result.print

    // execute program
    env.execute("Wikipedia Edit Monitoring")
  }

  /** Data type for words with count */
  case class UserWithEdits(user: String, edits: Long)
}
```

I also would like to know how to have the implementation using self-defined [`AggregateFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html).

**UPDATE**

I followed this documentation: [AggregateFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction), but have the following question:

In the source code of Interface [`AggregateFunction`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/310817035fef1d843b37e00ccd4a32efffaad3dc/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.java#L135) for release 1.3, you will see `add` indeed returns `void`:

```
void add(IN value, ACC accumulator);
```

But for version 1.4 [`AggregateFunction`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/07830e7897a42b5d12f0b33c42933c6ca78e70d3/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.java#L138), is is returning:

```
ACC add(IN value, ACC accumulator);
```

How should I handle this?

The Flink version I am using is `1.3.2` and the documentation for this version is not having `AggregateFunction`, but there is no release 1.4 in artifactory yet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find some documentation for `AggregateFunction` [in the Flink 1.4 docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction), including an example.

The version included in 1.3.2 is limited to being used with mutable accumulator types, where the add operation modifies the accumulator. This has been [fixed for Flink 1.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7837), but hasn't been released.

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AggregateFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer08
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.{WikipediaEditEvent, WikipediaEditsSource}

class SumAggregate extends AggregateFunction[WikipediaEditEvent, (String, Int), (String, Int)] {
  override def createAccumulator() = ("", 0)

  override def add(value: WikipediaEditEvent, accumulator: (String, Int)) = (value.getUser, value.getByteDiff + accumulator._2)

  override def getResult(accumulator: (String, Int)) = accumulator

  override def merge(a: (String, Int), b: (String, Int)) = (a._1, a._2 + b._2)
}

object WikipediaAnalysis extends App {
  val see: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val edits: DataStream[WikipediaEditEvent] = see.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource())

  val result: DataStream[(String, Int)] = edits
    .keyBy(_.getUser)
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
    .aggregate(new SumAggregate)
//    .fold(("", 0))((acc, event) => (event.getUser, acc._2 + event.getByteDiff))
  result.print()

  result.map(_.toString()).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer08[String]("localhost:9092", "wiki-result", new SimpleStringSchema()))
  see.execute("Wikipedia User Edit Volume")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Java land.